# UIButton not updating when called after web request

Tags: ios, swift, uibutton

I have the following function `enableEndButton()` called after a web request is complete.

```
func enableEndButton() {
    print("Start")
    buttonState = true
    go_button.setBackgroundImage(UIImage(named: "stop.png"), for: .normal)
    go_button.setTitle("Stop", for: .normal)
    print("Done")
}
```

The two prints are output but the button doesn't change until I tap it. How can I get this happening instantly?

This function is being called from within a dataTask as per:

```
let task = URLSession.shared.dataTask(with: url){
            data,response,error in
            if error != nil {
                print(error!)
            } else {
                weather_condition = self.parseWeatherJSON(weatherJSON: data!)
                //do something with weather_condition
                self.enableEndButton()
```

Comment: Where in your code are you calling this method? Can you show an example

Comment: It's in the anonymous function which requests the data, interprets the JSON then does something with the data -> directly after all this.

Comment: Can you give a code example? Would be helpful in diagnosing the problem

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try wrapping your call to enableEndButton in your URLSession completion in a Dispatch

```
DispatchQueue.main.async {
    self.enableEndButton()
}
```

Edit:

For clarity since URLSessions runs on a background thread and UI Updates must be done on the main thread you need to dispatch it explicitly to the main thread, however log statements are not required to be run on the main thread.

Comment: That's it. Why do the messages print but the set attributes don't?

Comment: @Sam updated the answer with a little more information

Answer (score 1):

Add this line,

```
go_button.isEnabled = true
```

Call `setbackgroundImage` and `setTitle` as soon as you initialise your button,

```
go_button = UIButton() 

// set enabled configuration
go_button.setBackgroundImage(UIImage(named: "stop.png"), for: .normal)
go_button.setTitle("Stop", for: .normal)

// set disabled configuration
go_button.setBackgroundImage(yourDisabled, for: .disabled)
go_button.setTitle(disabledTitle, for: .disabled)
```

Comment: I put this line underneath .setTitle but it doesn't happen instantly (ie when Start and Done are printer)...takes 10 seconds+. Any ideas?

Comment: In response to your edit, I've already initialised them to a particular background image and title, and am trying to change them after a web request has been completed.

Comment: Is your button disabled by default and then enabled after request completion?

Comment: Nope; the only changes I am making to it are changing the bg image and the title.

Comment: You can set `backgroundImage` and `title` for disabled and normal states. And when you toggle from disabled to enabled they will be automatically updated.

Comment: I have now used states but it still didn't solve the original problem. Thanks though!

Answer (score 0):

What I do is I always set the properties to nil or empty and then update them. Try the below function hope this will work.

```
go_button.setBackgroundImage(nil, for: .normal)
go_button.setTitle("", for: .normal)
```

Add these two lines at the start of your function.

Comment: Nope - the button isn't even being set to nil.

Comment: Are you using storyboard ? In storyboard you've option to set text and image differently for different types. In the storyboard check for state in the properties and in selected state set image and text and in the function just write a single line. yourButton.isSelected = true and try putting your function call in Dispatch.